# Power BI: Dashboard refresh fails occasionally with error DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, powerbi-datagateway

I have uploaded my Power BI file in Power BI Service (Power BI online) and the source of this file is Azure Sql database and for the credentials of this database in Power Service I have set virtual network data gateways.

So the problem is that refreshing of the dataset fails occasionally, means sometimes it refreshes with no problem and everything work fine but sometimes the refresh fails with the error below.

And one more thing is that data refreshing in Power BI Desktop (while creating the dashboard) is ok and has no problem.

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError",
      "pbi.error":{
         "code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError",
         "parameters":{
            
         },
         "details":[
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"-2147467259"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Invalid operation. The connection is closed.'"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"-2147467259"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"SQL"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"----------"
               }
            },
            {
               "code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason",
               "detail":{
                  "type":1,
                  "value":"DataSource.Error"
               }
            }
         ],
         "exceptionCulprit":1
      }
   }
} Table: ----------.
```

{The ---------- is private information}

Searched internet to find a solution but there was no helpful one.
Changed the structure of the data model in Power BI Desktop didn't help

Comment: Hope you tried restarting data source server as per [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/DM-GWPipeline-Gateway-MashupDataAccessError/m-p/1075859#M95063)

Comment: The data source is serverless Azure sql database which doesn't require restart.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Support is tough to get because the Power BI team wants to blame the Azure VNet team or the Azure SQL Database team, and both of those teams want to blame each other.  I need all 3 of them on a single call please.  Impossible.